# Rasa X deployment on shared server

Tags: docker, deployment, shared-hosting, rasa-x

I m trying to deploy rasa on my shared server. I have follow the [Docker Compose Installation](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/installation-and-setup/install/docker-compose) documentation to deploy rasa. And tried both with script and manual deployment. But it's not working.

As it  shared server my `80 and 443` ports are used, therefore i change `rasa/nginx` container ports to `8080 and 8443`, in `docker-compose.yml` file

When I hit to `http://<server_ip>:8080` its get redirected to `http://<server_ip>/api/health` and finally shows unable to connect.

And when I hit url `http://<server_ip>:8080/conversations` then it shows blank page with title "Rasa X".

**Edit:**

Still not able to figure out what was the issue. But now url `http://<server_ip>:8080/` returning `502 Bad Gateway`

From log `docker-compose logs:`

```
[error] 17#17: *40 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 43.239.112.255, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.64.6:5002/", host: "http://<server_ip>:8080"
```

Any idea what causing it?

Answer (score 1):

It seem that `RASA X 0.35.0` is not compatible with `RASA OPEN SOURCE 2.2.4` on server.

When I changed versions, from

```
RASA_X_VERSION=0.35.0
RASA_VERSION=2.2.4
RASA_X_DEMO_VERSION=0.35.0
```

to

```
RASA_X_VERSION=0.34.0
RASA_VERSION=2.1.2
RASA_X_DEMO_VERSION=0.34.0
```

Then it's works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you also define the ports in config.yml file as shown below for duckling server

[image]

Comment: I don't have config.yml file. I am referring to [Docker Compose Installation](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/installation-and-setup/install/docker-compose) for installation.